# How can I download a short clip from a long YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, video

I stream gameplay to YouTube and sometimes moments happen during gameplay that I feel would make a good GIF. I don't want to download the entire video just to make a 15 sec GIF. What do you think would be the best way to isolate a short clip from a long stream video?

Answer (score 1):

YouTube has/had an experimental feature which allows the creation of GIFs via the share button, but it's currently only enabled on select channels (example: vsauce3) and only in the old design.

Other than that, if you want to produce highlight clips, you can import your stream into the [YouTube editor](https://www.youtube.com/editor) which allows you to create a new video (a gif with sound!), or you can use third party services like [GIFs.com](http://gifs.com) or [imgur.com](https://imgur.com/vidgif).

The YouTube Live team is also looking to create better tools for streamers to enable things like that, so it may be that in the near-medium future there is going to be a better solution.